# Non-null fields validation only

Tags: java, rest, validation, spring-boot, http-patch

In my springboot app I'm using `PATCH` HTTP method to update an entity. Of course via DTO, not directly.

Since this is `PATCH` method I'm not all fields will be set and I want to validate (in terms of `javax.validation.constraints` package) only those fields that have value set (!=null).

So I have:

```
class SomeDTO {

   @Size(min = 5)
   String foo;
   @Min(2)
   Integer bar = 1; 

}
```

and need to validate `bar` field only, since `foo` has null value. What is the best mechanism for handling such requirements?

I'm using: `1.5.6.RELEASE`

Comment: The Size validator won't generate any error if foo is null.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks. Is it also true for all other validators?

Comment: Yes. The basic principle is that null is always accepted. It allows more flexibility: if the user doesn't provide the information, it's accepted. If the user provides it, it must be valid. If it's mandatry, and must be valid, then you combine the validator with NotNull.

Comment: @JBNizet, cool. I need to check this. Will do it on tomorrow, thanks!